# Use abstract class as template argument when using `std::function` like syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, abstract-class

Suppose I have a class that define template arguments like `std::function` syntax.

```
// Class that accept template arguments like std::function
template< class T >
class abstraction;

template< class TAbstract, class ...TDeriveds >
class abstraction< TAbstract(TDeriveds...) >
{
public:
    using abstract_component_t = TAbstract;

    abstraction()
    {
        int i = 0;
    }
};

// Abstract base class
class base
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

// Derived class
class derived : public base
{
public:
    void func() override
    {

    }
};
```

When I use an abstract class as template parameter to this class (`abstraction<base(derived)>`) I get these errors:

```
VC++ 2015.3 error: C2259: 'base': cannot instantiate abstract class
GCC 4.9.2 error: invalid abstract return type 'base'
```

I want to know is it a bug in compilers or it's forbidden to use abstract types with this syntax?

[Link](http://cpp.sh/7z5q) to sample source.

Comment: Maybe post full source here, that's clearer and it's not too much code after all. Comes down to writing <base(derived)> requiring base instantiation as it's a value type. I don't speak 'standardeze' well enough but likely someone else can come up with the exact standard rule forbidding this.

Comment: Interestingly, it compiles fine with clang 3.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template argument `TAbstract(TDeriveds...)` is a function type declaring a function taking `TDeriveds...` as arguments and returning a `TAbstract` by value. When returning by value it is necessary that objects of the value type can be instantiated. Objects of an abstract class *cannot* be instantiated, i.e., returning them by value is illegal (as is taking them as parameters). The relevant clause is 10.4 [class.abstract] paragraph 3:

> An abstract class shall not be used as a parameter type, as a function return type, or as the type of an explicit conversion. ...

You can, however, return abstract base classes by reference:

```
 template< class TAbstract, class ...TDeriveds >
 class abstraction< TAbstract&(TDeriveds...) >
 // ...
```

Sadly, that means that users of the class need to mention the `&` when using the class.

Comment: But there isn't any return type. `base` type has been used as template argument to another type. This syntax is only a `sugar syntax` to normal usage: `abstraction<base, derived>`

Comment: @MRB: the function declaration in the template specialisation *clearly* uses `TAbstract` (which gets replaced by `base`) as a return type - that is where it is illegal.

Comment: You are saying that by using `< TAbstract(TDeriveds...) >` syntax, I'm using a function declaration? So how it compiles in `clang`?

Comment: Yes, the template arguments of the form `R(A...)` are function types. I'm not entirely sure what the standard says about return types with respect to them being abstract: there is a chance that the diagnosis is done at different times by different compilers and that `clang` delays the check whether the return type can actually be instantiated until use while the other compilers check when the type is used.

Comment: That now make sense for me. We have a template class that we specialized it for a function type and through it we extract exact types based on it's return type and function parameters. It was a misunderstanding by me that I though it is a special syntax. that's why I love C++, every thing about it is surprising... :)

Comment: @MRB You're explicitly making a function type, why surprised that the normal rules for function types apply? You could always do `abstraction<TAbstract, TDeriveds...>` and avoid the problem.

Comment: Interesting use of the `std::function` object syntax with `R` for `Base*` and `A...` for `Deriveds...` types. Pardon my confusion, but could I then use this in some (simple) cases as a factory, I mean without having a factory class? Including perhaps lambda versions. Are there any gotchas?

Comment: @Barry I hadn't considered that this syntax is actually a specialization for a function type. I had used this syntax many times in my class definitions but didn't realize this fact anytime.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, using TAbstract& (or a pointer type) as a type argument for your class will solve the problem.

The problem is trivial: you cannot return an instance of an abstract class. Instead, you can return a reference or a pointer of type TAbstract.